# Why won't my custom Google map center on the point I'm asking it to?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've embedded a Google map into a website I'm working on. The website is http://www.paulgrantdesign.com/aberdeen (note that for smaller monitors, I have NOT completed the conditional responsive designing yet)

If you click Location on the right, it opens up a custom Google map that I'm trying to implement. The center of the map when you load this screen is not the position that should be centered. If you grab the center point, and drag it to the top right, you can see a red outlined spot. The center of the outlined area should be centered. I know that I have the proper coordinates in the code, because when I punch the coordinates back into maps.google.com it shows me the proper spot. Why is that position loading to the bottom left?

```
    <script>
      function initialize() {

        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.518191,-110.331709),
          zoom: 15,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
        var styles = [
  {
    stylers: [
      { hue: "#00ffe6" },
      { saturation: -20 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      { lightness: 100 },
      { visibility: "simplified" }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "on" }
    ]
  }
];
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(53.52235,-110.337503),
    new google.maps.LatLng(53.522987,-110.333168),
    new google.maps.LatLng(53.514414,-110.321967),
    new google.maps.LatLng(53.514593,-110.337503),
    new google.maps.LatLng(53.52235,-110.337503),
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
map.setOptions({styles: styles});
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Comment: If I take the code and run it, it shows the map and the polyline, centered. It seems to work. However, If I go to your site with FireFox, I see a map but no polyline. If I use Chrome, I dont see anything at all. So my guess is that you have some other issues than the code above ..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wait to initialize your map.
The first time I run your website, the pluggin take a long time to load. At this step, the animated menu has finished its transition.

The second time, the map load quickly. And your Menu is still animated.

So, your map load within a small width div (like 100px), and your spot is centered. But your menu is sill sliding, and your map grow with it, and the spot goes left.

Is this clear enought ?
I 'm not sure of this, but you shoudl try to initialize your map in a callback.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're saying. I appreciate the feedback!